# Do I use critical section when different object write the same file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I write the class to keep error message record, and some objects will import it to keep its error message record. I want all of message to write in the same file.
Do I need to use critical section ?

If I do. Is the following code useful ?

```
global critical_section
critical_section = 0

class Recorder (object):
    ...
    def writeError(self, title, content):
        global critical_section
        while critical_section != 0 :
            pass
        critical_section = 1
        file = open("system_error.log", "a")
        msg = "[ "+title+" ] "+time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S : ")+content
        file.write(msg)
        file.close()
        critical_section = 0
    ...
```

Comment: Are you using different threads (you only speak about different objects). You may have a look at [Python's Semaphores](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html?highlight=semaphore#threading.Semaphore) to implement this.

Comment: Your critical_section variable doesn't solve the problem: it is possible that both threads simultaneously finish the `while critical_section != 0` loop (or before either sets the variable anyway) and then both set it to 1. Use semaphores.

Comment: I write this program to keep record of error message of cluster node. The error log file be created on master. Every connection between master and node is a thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First occurence of "global" keyword is useless. This variable is already global.
2. You're using active waiting. It is ugly as f*ck. This is why constructs like semaphore or lock exist. Check out module [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).
3. GLOBALS ARE UGLY AND WRONG. Create class-level variable `file_lock` and use it. In the end your code may look like this:

```
from threading import Lock

class Recorder(object):
    file_lock = Lock()
    def writeError(self, title, content):
        with type(self).file_lock:
            with open("system_error.log", "a") as f:
                msg = ...
                f.write(msg)
```

Why do I use `type(self).file_lock` instead of `self.file_lock`? Because there MAY be instance-level variable file_lock too, and I want to ensure that we're using class-level lock.

Yet another thing is that while appending to file (at least at linux, checked a moment ago) you can write from many places to the same file, and first flushing process will write first. Anyhow, it is good practice to be sure that only one person at the time will write to given file.

As you see, I used context managers (`with open/lock`) instead of `f=open(...)` or `lock.acquire()`. It has many advantages - you are sure that `file.close()` or `lock.release()` will be called even it exception is raised, and your code is more readable, which is GREAT advantage.

**PS. Important**: see Bakuriu's comment to this post, I forgot to mention that and that is kinda crucial.

Comment: Note that *in other circumstances*, using `type(self)` can create infinite loops if combined with inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation. I probably know how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [logging API provided by python](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file).

Comment: @Cilyan No, `logging` **is** thread safe. It isn't *process* safe, which is a different thing. Since the OP *never* mentioned using multiple *processes* it's absolutely fine to use `logging`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to lock access to a file when using thread, otherwise strange things might happen.

If you use the Python Thread modul you could use it like this:

```
import thread
lock=thread.allocate_lock()
...
class Recorder (object):
    ...
    def writeError(self, title, content):
        lock.acquire() 
        file = open("system_error.log", "a")
        msg = "[ "+title+" ] "+time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S : ")+content
        file.write(msg)
        file.close()
        lock.release()
```

Comment: Or better `with lock`, to ensure the lock is actually released even if an unexpected condition arises while processing the file.

Comment: +1 for a good point! I will leave my Answer as it is though, as it should only show a minimal Example and ther are like a thousand way to make it better.